# UISearchBar input string to escaped unicode characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

I have a search bar which user can type in English, Chinese or Pinyin. The `UISearchBar` returns the string as `NSString`.  What I need to do with the string is convert it into its UTF-8 unicode character but only for character that are used in Chinese and Pinyin.

Here are a couple of scenarios. The unicode I just made up while typing so it is not correct but I am just using it as example the outcome is whats important.

```
   SEARCH INPUT   |      NSString should look like              
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
| hello world     |  hello world                              |
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Nǐ zěnme yàng   |  N\u3435 z\u2343nme y\u1111ng             |
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
| 你怎么样         |  \u3435\u9995\u3885\u3445                 |
+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

I have done this successfully with JavaScript and PHP but Objective-C is a new realm for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSData *dataString = [@"你怎么样" dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
    NSString *cleanedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataString encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Result: `\u4f60\u600e\u4e48\u6837`

OR

```
+ (NSString*) escapeUnicodeString:(NSString*)string
{
    NSString* escapedString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];
    escapedString = [escapedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
    NSData* data = [escapedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    size_t bytesRead = 0;
    const char* bytes = data.bytes;
    NSMutableString* encodedString = [NSMutableString string];
    while (bytesRead < data.length)
    {
        uint16_t code = *((uint16_t*) &bytes[bytesRead]);
        if (code > 0x007E)
        {
            [encodedString appendFormat:@"\\u%04X", code];
        }
        else
        {
            [encodedString appendFormat:@"%C", code];
        }
        bytesRead += sizeof(uint16_t);
    }
    return encodedString;
}
```

Result: `\u4F60\u600E\u4E48\u6837`

[Source](https://github.com/GameAid/Toddler-Taxonomist/blob/master/Toddler%20Taxonomist/NSString+UnicodeUtilities.m)

Comment: AWESOME, +(NSString*) escapeUnicodeString:(NSString*)string  is what did it, thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You saved my life with your method, thank you guy ;)